# Finding all holomorphic functions that satisfy an integral inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find all the holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ that satisfies

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{it})|dt \leq r^{\pi} $$
for all $r >0.$

All I could find is that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0 $ for $n=0,1,2,3$ since $\pi >3$ using Cauchy estimates. Usually this sort of questions result in $f$ being a polynomial or a constant so  probably there's more to say. I would like some hint on this question.

Comment: Check carefully Cauchy's estimates' and this inequality's consequence to see if you get $n< \pi$ or $\pi<n$.

Comment: Hint: depending on what you are presented with, you can make $r$ tend to $0$ or to $+\infty$ to derive conclusions.

Comment: It would also help if you could edit your post with what you've tried exactly so that we can better see where you are stuck. For example, why did the Cauchy estimates give you that the first derivatives are zero, and why didn't it generalise to higher derivatives?

Comment: @BrunoB I've solved the problem shortly after NDB commented. When $n \geq 4$ $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ too in a similar manner. Then assuming $f$ is holomorphic it has a series representation around $0$ in which the coefficients are given by $f^{(n)}(0)/n!$ This means that $f$ is identically $0.$ Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Say $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. Then for every $m\in\mathbb N$,
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(r\mathrm{e}^{it})|\,dt\ge 
\Big|\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(r\mathrm{e}^{it})\,\mathrm{e}^{-imt}\,dt\,\Big|
=\Big|\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n r^n\mathrm{e}^{int}\,\mathrm{e}^{-imt}\,dt\,\Big| =2\pi|a_m|r^m.
$$